# If $f \in C_{u}(U \times [0,T])$ then is it true that $f(\cdot,t) \in C_{u}([0,T])$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, holder-spaces

Let $f:=f(x,t)$ belong to the parabolic Hölder space  $C^{1,\beta}(U\times [0,T])$ where $U$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb R^2$ and $0<\beta <1$. This yields that $f$ is a Hölder continuous function in both space and time variables with exponents $1$ and $\beta$ correspondigly.

If not mistaken, the Hölder continuity of $f$ implies that $f$ is also uniform continuous in both variables.

QUESTION: If I consider $f$ as a function only of time $t$ then is $f(\cdot,t)$ uniformly continuous in the sense that $\; \exists \delta >0$ with $\vert t_1-t_2 \vert \le \delta$ such that $\vert f(\cdot,t_1)-f(\cdot,t_2) \vert < \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon >0$ $(*)$?

If my whole argument is false, then is the Hölder continuity sufficient in order to deduce something similar to $(*)$ for $t \to f(\cdot,t)$?

The more I'm getting my head around this, the more puzzled I get so I would appreciate any help or hint.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Since $|u-v|\leq ||(u,t)-(v,s)||,$ the fact that $f$ is uniformly continuous implies that $f(\cdot,t)$ is, indeed, uniformly continuous.

Comment: Also, since both $U$ and $[0,T]$ is compact, you really only need continuity of $f$ to conclude uniform continuity. If either $U$ or your interval were open, you'd need something stronger - such as Hölder continuity.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Of course! I feel I overcomplicated stuff here! Thanks a lot!